# Divide log record of String format to columns in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, logging

What I have as an input is a log line of String format:

```
- - - [DA/MM/YEAR:HH:MM:SEC +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" "/somepath.../index.html" 111 123 "-" "-" 9792 0 11.112.1.112->11.112.1.121 231xx
```

What i'm trying to do is to transform this string into an array of format:

```
[date],[request text],[ip],[port],[protocol] etc
```

Those columns are just an example, so you can get my idea.

Currently i'm trying to replace every

```
[space]" -> ,"
```

And after this to use the "," (comma) as a separator.

Maybe you guys have some more efficient ideas of doing it, i would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a regex pattern for your logger, for example like:

```
String input = "- - - [DA/MM/YEAR:HH:MM:SEC +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" \"/somepath.../index.html\" 111 123 \"-\" \"-\" 9792 0 11.112.1.112->11.112.1.121 231xx";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([^\\s+]*)\\s+(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(7));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(8));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(9));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(10));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(11));
 }
```

Sure, it looks a little bit awkward, but it simply splits your log message into the groups of data. Regexes groups are repeating in the pattern to determine log-message content, all the groups are:

`\\[([^\\]]*)\\]` all content between `[` and `]`

`"([^"]*)"` all content between nearest `"` signs

`(\d+)` group af digits

`([^\s+]*)` all content between spaces, in your case is to get ip addresses `11.112.1.112->11.112.1.121`

`(.*)` to get all the text at the end of the message

Sure, it is possible to spit you message by spaces or some other signs, but it could lead to problems, if your message will contain this signs in text part. So, it could be realyy better to use regex, because logger has concrete formatting for the messages.

Comment: Great, thank you. Pretty straightforward solution :) , works perfectly, now trying to understand why exactly it works

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, it could be usefull to understand, how does grouping work in Java http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

String.split will do it for you:

```
String log = "date req data";
String[] logArray = log.split(" "); //{{date}{req}{data}} array
```

Comment: that is not a good solution. just try it yourself for the log line from the answer and take a look at the results you'll get

Comment: Unfortunately, this will simply divide entire string by [space]. The only solution i can think of is first to devide it by comma, then devide those new strings by [space], although it doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution